# Facebook:Is it possible to post on wall using multi-friend-selector? Or can I use JQUERY with php-sdk(fbml, not iframe)

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fbml

I am new to facebook development.
I am using PHP-FBML with Graph API.

Edited: Or can I use JQUERY with php-sdk(fbml, not iframe). If yes then how?

Please someone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because it's against [the policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

Section **IV.5**

> You must not provide users with the
>   option to publish the same Stream
>   story to more than one friend's wall
>   at a time.

Comment: This policy no longer exists 11/27/11.

Answer (score 1):

`<fb:multi-friend-selector>` can be used only to send invites inside a request form.

You can use `<fb:fb:multi-friend-input>` though, which is also friend selector but slightly different. If you put it inside your own `<form>` it should pass selected friend ids with form submission. You can read about this process [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-input) in details.

Once form is submitted you need to process it on PHP side. Loop through array of selected friends and send posts to their wall using PHP SDK (you can read [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing) how to do it through Graph API).

jQuery doesn't work inside FBML, but you won't need it for this anyway.